# SQLAlchemy: What is the difference beetween CheckConstraint and @validates

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In a SQLAlchemy model what is the difference between adding a CheckConstraint and adding a @validates decorated validation method? Is the one acting on the database level and the other one not? And are there any guidelines when to use which?

Specifically, what is the difference between using

```
__table_args__ = (CheckConstraint('to_node_id != from_node_id'), )
```

and

```
@validates('from_node', 'to_node')
def validate_nodes_are_different(self, key, field):
    if key == 'to_node' and field and field is self.from_node:
            raise ValueError
    elif key == 'from_node' and field and field is self.to_node:
            raise ValueError
    return field
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckConstraint` is a database-level check; `@validates` is a Python-level check. A database-level check is more universal; the constraint is satisfied even if you access the database through other means. A Python-level check is more expressive; you can usually check for complicated constraints more easily.

The other thing you should consider is what happens when you want to change the constraint. A `CHECK` constraint will force you to change existing data to conform when you change the constraint. A Python-level constraint allows you to force only new data to conform to the constraint.

Comment: Thanks! So the usecase above (checking that two nodes in a relation are actually different) or checking that start_date comes before end_date would be candidates for a database level constraint because that is uncomplicated and unlikely to change, but something like checking that a string is a valid email adress would be something done as a python decorator, right?

Comment: @spbks Sure, that sounds reasonable. It's important to not take this as a hard and fast rule, but instead to understand the implications of your choice.